# How to obtain a simple fingerprint image using C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, fingerprint

Looking for a solution to grab a fingerprint image using the attached reader and C#. I will then store it to a database as a picture.

What's the simplest way to accomplish the goal? I'd prefer minimum external dependencies, especially no COM dependencies.

Comment: Is the reader a TWAIN device?

Comment: @John - I've dealt with a whole bunch of readers and none of them have supported TWAIN. Besides, TWAIN is ancient and I'd highly recommend avoiding it at all costs. The name itself is a joke about how horrible it is.

Comment: What kind of reader are you using ?

Comment: I'm not sure. It shows as "TouchStrip Fingerprint Sensor (WBF advanced mode)" in Windows Device Manager.

Comment: @LoveDotNet try here http://uplic.authentec.com/solutions/physical/embedded/development_kits.asp

Comment: @LoveDotNet TWAIN may be old (last updated 2009) but at least in some ways it is a standard and I am unsure of anything that replaced it? Either way I guess it does not help your situation. Sorry could not help more

Comment: @LoveDotNet [Here](http://uplic.authentec.com/solutions/pc_and_networking/sdks/default.asp#Biometric%20Services%20API%20%28BSAPI%29) their SDK includes a .net samples ( `extended sample code (Visual Basic and C#)` )

Comment: You said "using the attached reader" - did you mean to include a link or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was under impression there should be some generic access approach that can be used for any fingerprint reader.

After some research, it seems that each specific fingerprint device requires a particular SDK, so I found and downloaded an appropriate package for my device.

Answer (score 2):

This is simplest solution I found for acquisition of fingerprint image from scanners.

The solution is to

1. Use a TWAIN compatible fingerprint device. You can find the list of TWAIN compatible devices **[here](http://code.google.com/p/online-fingerprint-verification-sdk/wiki/Compatible_Scanners)**. The list is still draft, probably more devices will added soon in the list.
2. Use TWAIN interfaces to access the device from you C# program. Check out http://www.dynamsoft.com/ they have the required libraries. It's paid, but trail version are also available.
3. From the device, you will get a image in JPEG or PNG format. Do whatever you want to do.

The thing here is every vendor have there own sdk to access their devices (marketing strategies!!), and there is **no common standard** for accessing those devices. TWAIN is an open standard for image acquisition, already being used with digital-cameras, scanners, etc.

This is a standard way accessing the devices. Your software will be able to access any device which implement TWAIN..!! :)